# Creating custom attribute programmaticaly default value

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, default

How to set default value to "Yes" in generated select element? I created installation script and attribute is created perfectly. But on create/edit page of product I get No selected attribute for option.

```
<select class=" select" name="product[abroad_shipping]" id="abroad_shipping">
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>
</select>



<?php

/* @var $this Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/* @var $setup Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$setup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'abroad_shipping');

$attributeData = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Possible abroad shipping',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default_value' => '1',
    'default' => array('1'),
//  'default' => '1',
//    'option' => array(
//        'values' => 
//        array(
//            0 => 'Yes',
//            1 => 'No'
//        )
//        ),
);

$setId = $setup->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'my_custom_set');
$groupId = $setup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $setId, null);
$setup->addAttribute($entityTypeId, 'abroad_shipping', $attributeData);
$setup->addAttributeToGroup($entityTypeId, $setId, $groupId, 'abroad_shipping', 90);

$installer->endSetup();
```

I tried default, default value, integer default, string default, array. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

`default` is the correct method for setting default values for the drop down, 
For example, My custom options are like,

```
Myoption-1
Myoption-2
Myoption-3
Myoption-4
Myoption-5
```

And your installer script should be like this,

```
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mydropdown",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "My Drop down",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "mymodule/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14042221240",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "2",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "This is My Drop down option"

    ));
```

Here the `default` having values is `2`. That means `Myoption-2` is the default option. You may be entered wrong value. check the value of that option that you need to set as a `default`.

Comment: No, still not working.

Comment: You may set multiple default options..make sure about this ..

Comment: I know what's wrong. When I create product default value is set correctly. When I edit product that already exists - value is set to "No" which is last option in select. I have to update all product values for this column.